# Manejo de excepciones con URLs en Python

Tags: python-3.x, url

Estoy diseñando una app en python-3 que lee de una base de datos sqlite rutas url: si la primer ruta no funciona debería ir a la segunda y así sucesivamente, hasta encontrar una url que sí funcione. El problema es que cuando encuentra la primer url que no funciona la app se rompe; intenté try y catch, pero no sé manejar bien las excepciones:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\usuarioPersonal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn conn = connection.create_connection( File "C:\Users\usuarioPersonal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 72, in create_connection for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM): File "C:\Users\usuarioPersonal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 955, in getaddrinfo for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags): socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Leí sobre error gaierror y no pude solucionarlo. ¿Cómo manejar las excepciones url y que pueda buscar en la próxima url de la db?

Paso el código:

```py
import http.client as httplib
import requests
import sqlite3
import threading
import time

url = "" #Esta es la url 'u1', 'u2', 'u3'
recorreUrl = 4 # Comienza en el 4 y termina en el 6 (u1, u2, u3)
cantidad = 1 # Cantidad son las películas que tengo en la bd
cantCanales = 0 # La uso para comparar si ya llegué al final de cantidad
c = 0        # c es el valor de la url que está funcionando
```

#------ Cantidad Canales -------------------

```py
def canalesTotales():
    global cantCanales
    conn = sqlite3.connect('pelis.db')
    MyCursor = conn.cursor()
    MyCursor.execute("SELECT * from pelis")    
    for dat in MyCursor:
        cantCanales = cantCanales + 1 #  Tengo cantidad de canales
        print("Canales: "+str(cantCanales))
    recorrerUrl()
```

#-----------------------------

```py
def recorrerUrl():
    global recorreUrl
    global cantidad
    # Aquí recorreUrl (Es desde el 4 al 7 donde están las urls)
    if recorreUrl < 7:
        print(f"Menos de 7 - url {recorreUrl}") # Esto es para ver que 
              #iba pasando
        #print(f'Cantidad: {cantidad}')  # Cantidad cambia cuando ya 
               #revisé que 'recorreUrl' está funcionando y paso a la 
               #próxima película
        #revisarWeb() # Llama a la función (aquí la comenté porque me 
                      #daba error para pegar el código, pero hay que 
                      #quitar el comentario para que funcione
    


    if recorreUrl == 7:
        revisarWeb()
        recorreUrl = 4
        print(f"Igual a 7 - url {recorreUrl}")
        print(f"Cantidad: {cantidad}")
        cantidad = cantidad + 1
```

```py
def revisarWeb():
    global cantidad
    global recorreUrl
    global cantCanales
    
    conn = sqlite3.connect('pelis.db')
    MyCursor = conn.cursor()
    MyCursor.execute(f"SELECT * from `pelis` WHERE `id`='{cantidad}'")
    for dat in MyCursor:
        if dat != 0:
            url = dat[recorreUrl] # En la bd sqlite3 tengo tres url 
                                  # u1(4), u2(5), u3(6) por eso el 
                                  # recorreUrl             
            c = int(dat[7]) # dat[7] es donde está guardando el numero 
                            # u1, o u2, o u3 que está funcionando
#-------- Busca la pagina ---------- 
            if url != "":
                get = requests.get(url)
                print("Buscando página...")
                # Si se encuentra la página
                if get.status_code == 200:
                    # Compara ambos valores si son iguales suma 1 a 
                    # cantidad para que pase a # leer otra película
                    if recorreUrl == c:  
                        if cantidad < cantCanales:
                            cantidad = cantidad + 1
                            recorreUrl = 4 
# Aquí el valor vuelve a 4 para la próxima lectura de cada u1, u2, u3
                            recorrerUrl()
                        if cantidad == cantCanales: 
# En este caso pasa a llamar al timer para que revise cada cierto tiempo # si las u1, u2, u3 están bien
                            timer()
     conn.close() 
canalesTotales()
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y coloca el código para ver en qué parte está fallando y así poder ayudarte.

Comment: @JhovannyUribe los mensajes de error también mejor pedirlos como texto, ya que [no todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).

Answer (score 0):

Para manejar las excepciones y permitir que tu programa continúe con la siguiente URL en caso de un error, puedes utilizar bloques try y except alrededor del código que verifica si la URL es válida. Además, es una buena práctica manejar el caso en el que todas las URLs fallan para evitar que tu programa se rompa. Aquí hay una versión modificada de tu código que hace eso:

```
import requests
import sqlite3
import time

# ... 

def revisarWeb():
    global cantidad
    global recorreUrl
    global cantCanales
    
    conn = sqlite3.connect('pelis.db')
    MyCursor = conn.cursor()
    MyCursor.execute(f"SELECT * from `pelis` WHERE `id`='{cantidad}'")
    for dat in MyCursor:
        if dat != 0:
            url = dat[recorreUrl]  # En la bd sqlite3 tengo tres URL u1(4), u2(5), u3(6) por eso el recorreUrl             
            c = int(dat[7])  # dat[7] es donde está guardando el número u1, u2, u3 que está funcionando

            if url != "":
                try:
                    get = requests.get(url)
                    print("Buscando página...")

                    # Si se encuentra la página
                    if get.status_code == 200:
                        # Compara ambos valores si son iguales suma 1 a cantidad para que pase a leer otra película
                        if recorreUrl == c:
                            if cantidad < cantCanales:
                                cantidad = cantidad + 1
                                recorreUrl = 4  # El valor vuelve a 4 para la próxima lectura de cada u1, u2, u3
                                recorrerUrl()
                            if cantidad == cantCanales:
                                # En este caso pasa a llamar al temporizador para que revise cada cierto tiempo si las u1, u2, u3 están bien
                                timer()

                except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                    # Manejo de excepción en caso de error de conexión o solicitud HTTP
                    print(f"Error al acceder a la URL: {url}")
                    recorrerUrl()

    conn.close()

# ...
```

En este código, se envia la solicitud `requests.get(url)` en un bloque try-except para manejar excepciones relacionadas con errores de conexión o de solicitud HTTP. Si se produce una excepción, se imprimirá un mensaje de error y se llamará a la función `recorrerUrl()` para continuar con la siguiente URL.

Este enfoque evita que el programa se rompa cuando se encuentra una URL que no funciona y permite que continúe con la siguiente URL en la secuencia.

Comment: Revolucion for Monica!! Gracias!! Voy a probar tu código, gracias de corazón muchas gracias, que tengas un gran día.